# CakePHP baked project, moved to plugin, relations not working?

Tags: cakephp, model

I baked a project in CakePHP, which was working great.  I then moved it to a plugin called "MobileFort."  I was able to get everything functioning from a test app, except my model relations.  I added "MobileFort." before all of the class names, but still no joy.

Example index (from the "User" controller... just default bake):

```
    public function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

The relevant model relations:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'SystemNotice' => array(
        'className' => 'MobileFort.SystemNotice',
        'foreignKey' => 'system_notice_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'TicketMessage' => array(
        'className' => 'MobileFort.TicketMessage',
        'foreignKey' => 'ticket_message_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

public $hasMany = array(
    'SystemNotice' => array(
        'className' => 'MobileFort.SystemNotice',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'TicketMessageSent' => array(
        'className' => 'MobileFort.TicketMessage',
        'foreignKey' => 'to_user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'TicketMessageReceived' => array(
        'className' => 'MobileFort.TicketMessage',
        'foreignKey' => 'from_user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
);
```

Aand the relevant bit of the view:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo h($user['User']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo h($user['User']['username']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link($user['SystemNotice']['title'], array('controller' => 'system_notices', 'action' => 'view', $user['SystemNotice']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link($user['TicketMessage']['subject'], array('controller' => 'ticket_messages', 'action' => 'view', $user['TicketMessage']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What on earth am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, after a lot of fidgeting with it, the problem was involving my controller using a name that didn't follow convention.  I was using the `uses` attribute as would be expected:

`public $uses = array('User');`

It needed the `MobileFort.` added to the front of `User`.

I didn't realize that because, for some reason, it was otherwise working (the page would load, I could get all the other user data, etc... it just wouldn't load associated models).

I think the situation is so unique it probably rarely came up.